# uml class diagram for train schedule

Tags: class

i want draw uml class diagram for train schedule

how to draw it

methods
add train
delete train
update rain
search train

And if the schdule class is a composition to system, would the method for creating a new schedule have to be in the system class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about what information should be included in the train schedule at first, which will be the instance variables in your class. Naming some of the obvious ones: TrainNumber, ScheduledTrainTime, ExpectedTrainTime, TrainStatus.

According to the above properties, you may add methods like updateExpectedTrainTime, updateTrainStatus, getTrainStatus. etc.

Personally, I would say the Train class may contain the TrainSchedule class, and train's schedule is updated via Train class